# Bash issue when open terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

When I open terminal it appears this

```
-bash: geant4.sh: No such file or directory
```

It doesn't affect anything but I would like to know why this is happeneing. I checked .bashrc, .profile, .bash_profile and there is nothing called geant4.sh (or something similar). Where should I look for this?

Comment: Check also files sourced from the rc and profiles, and also /etc/bashrc and similar.

Comment: Could happen at any level of thecall stack. Run as login shell in verbose mode and study the output.

Comment: try running `bash -lvx` & locate your error string in that. The figure out which script is trying to call geant4.sh.